# PostgreSQL Sum function is an invalid type name?

Tags: postgresql, function, sum, syntax-error, pgadmin

So, I'm trying to create a function that will find the total sum of the "total_rental_time" variable from the "Rental_Instances" table that corresponds to a specific "Category_id", then change that sum into a varchar format for easy-reading.
For some reason however, the sum function is not working as intended. This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION readable_date_time_format (cat_id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
   BEGIN
      DECLARE rental_num INT;
      DECLARE total_time_rented VARCHAR(11);
      SELECT SUM(total_rental_time)
         FROM rental_instances
         WHERE rental_instances.category_id = cat_id
         INTO rental_num;
      total_time_rented = CONCAT(rental_num, ' Days');
      RETURN total_rental_time;
   END;
$$;
```

I am writing it into pgADMIN, and when I go to run it, I get this error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM2Wi.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax is `select ... into ... from ... where ...` : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: why do you need a function for this?

Comment: In plpgsql, variable declarations come before BEGIN.

Comment: @GMB that was it! I did the syntax wrong... wow! Thanks so much!

Comment: For something like this you don't need a function (a view works just as fine), and if you do use a function, you don't need plpgsql since sql is good enough.

Comment: @GMB: That's the SQL `SELECT INTO` statement, which is unrelated to the PL/pgSQL `SELECT INTO` statement. A mess, I know....